# Efeito escrita dinamica de texto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Gostaria de usar em um projeto web um efeito que "escreve" o texto na tela como se fosse alguém digitando, pausadamente.

Tipo se a sentença for "Ola mundo" ele vai mostrar:

Entenda o "|" como o cursor da escrita:

"O|"

E depois de uns 0.2 segundos:

```
"OL|"
"OLA |"
"OLA M|"
"OLA MU|"
"OLA MUN|"
```

Assim por diante.

E depois ele voltasse se apagando:

```
"OLA MUN|"
"OLA MU|"
"OLA M|"
"OLA |"
```

Não sei nem mais o que tentar, se souberem o nome desse efeito avisem, provavelmente deve ser com javascript e css, ou algum plugin.

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda, obrigado.

Comment: poste seu código para sabermos em que parte da possível solução chegou. Dessa forma podemos auxiliar melhor

Answer (score 6):

O efeito se chama **typewriter**

Segue um exemplo simples apenas com CSS, cada caractere da frase que vc quer representa um `animation:steps()` como "Olá mundo!" tem 10 caracteres vc vai precisar de `steps(10)` da mesma forma de acordo com o tamanho da frase vc precisa ajustar o `width`. Já as animações vc usa o `@keyframes` para fazer

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
      background-color: black;
      display: flex;
}
.line {
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      margin: auto;
      border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      font-size: 180%;
      text-align: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;

}
/*Animação*/
.anim-typewriter {
      animation: typewriter 4s steps(9) 500ms infinite,
      blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(9) infinite normal;
}
@keyframes typewriter {
      0% {
            width: 0px;
      }
      10% {
            width: 0px;
      }
      25% {
            width: 160px;
      }
      75% {
            width: 160px;
      }
      90% {
            width: 0px;
      }
      100% {
            width: 0px;
      }
}
@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
      from {
            border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      }
      to {
            border-right-color: transparent;
      }
}
```

```html
<p class="line anim-typewriter">Olá Mundo!</p>
```

Se quiser algo mais sofisticado com jQuery etc, sugiro essas duas opções

**TypewriterJS** https://safi.me.uk/typewriterjs/

**Typed.Js** https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Esse exemplo fiz usando o TypewriterJS também tem o link do projeto no GitHub https://github.com/tameemsafi/typewriterjs

```js
var app = document.getElementById('app');

var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
    loop: true
});

typewriter.typeString('Olá Mundo!!!')
    .pauseFor(2500)
    .deleteAll()
    .typeString('Seu texto está aqui')
    .pauseFor(2500)
    .deleteChars(9)
    .typeString('ou não...')
    .start();
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://safi.me.uk/typewriterjs/js/typewriter.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Já tem uma resposta bastante boa e prática do @hugocsl sobre que bibliotecas utilizar para conseguir esse efeito, e também de como as utilizar. No entanto de forma a ficar como referência também, mostro como poderia implementar algo desse género, ainda que numa versão bastante simplificada.

Iria precisar de [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) ou [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) para conseguir criar ações temporizadas, e a cada passo de tempo adicionaria uma letra do texto ao conteudo de um `<div>` por exemplo, através de [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) ou [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Exemplo:

```js
const resultado = document.querySelector(".conteudo");
const inputTexto = document.getElementById("texto");

document.getElementById("inserir").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let texto = inputTexto.value; //obter o texto do input a ser mostrado
  let letra = 0; //letra em que vai
  resultado.textContent = ""; //limpar o que estava escrito antes
  
  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (letra < texto.length){ //se ainda não chegou ao fim
      //escreve a letra e avança para a próxima
      resultado.textContent += texto[letra++]; 
    }
    else { //se chegou ao fim
      clearInterval(timer); //para a temporização
    }
  }, 200); //200 milisegundos entre cada letra
});
```

```css
.cursor {
  color: #2E3D48;
  animation: 0.5s blink step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
Texto a inserir: <input type="text" id="texto">
<button id="inserir">Inserir</button>
<div>
  <span class="conteudo"></span><span class="cursor">|</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito massa! E ainda é com JS puro!